# Conflict between Sharepoint List Name and Document Library Name

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I my share point site I have one List named "People List" and one Wiki Page Library named "People". I have created one visual webpart to display data from People list. I have created webpart property to read listname.The webpart property name for my visual webpart is "People". When I check whether list exists in my site  using the following function it returns true:-

```
 public static bool isListExists(SPWeb spWeb, string listName)
        {
            return spWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName) != null;
        }
```

But there is no List named "People" exists in my site. Only wiki page library named "People" exists. When I added my webpart in  "MySite/People/default.aspx" page I got error.

```
Column 'Title' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Column 'Title' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.


Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Column 'Title' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetField(String strName, Boolean bThrowException) +26422968
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowException) +47
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_Item(String fieldName) +12
   CL.DanceStudio.Portal.CLDance_Instructor.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Select>b__1() +1155
   Microsoft.SharePoint.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2() +729
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +27491206
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) +27194345
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +93
   CL.DanceStudio.Portal.CLDance_Instructor.CLDance_InstructorUserControl.Select() +291
   CL.DanceStudio.Portal.CLDance_Instructor.CLDance_InstructorUserControl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +52
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +350
   CL.DanceStudio.Portal.CLDance_Instructor.CLDance_Instructor.CreateChildControls() +194
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

I think it is due to name conflict. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: what is the listname u are giving to the function?

Comment: I  have given "People" as list name in the webpart property. So the "People" is the list name that passing to the function.

Comment: Does People list have a column named Title?

Comment: Yes . I am using default Title column in sharepoint list.